How far can an AC signal actually go?
I have the following circuit schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The systems is a water level control circuit, in which a signal is sent from the water level sensor (with water ON, without water OFF.) It is behaving quite oddly.  Sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't.
At first I thought it would have been a problem of temperature since the relay has a 55ºC maximum operating temperature, but after measuring it around 35 degrees I started thinking that the problem clearly would be the distance, since I set up another circuit just like the one above but with 400-meter long wires and it is working as expected. I could not measure voltage values or anything else since I'm not locally present, but I am sure the wires are not shorting to ground or open.

How does distance play a role when designing such circuit?
Is wire capacitance actually disturbing the circuit operation and eventually disrupting the signal?
Would wiring up again with a 48V DC supply (and of course a 48V DC relay) actually solve the problem?


what do you mean by won't work? ... what does it do?

@jsotola sometimes the relay is activated when the sensor is activated. However, sometimes it doesn't matter the sensor position, the relay will not switch.

Electrically not an issue but there could be local regulations for AC wire run. 4 mm^2 is very thick for a 3 W load. Is it existing is how come?

@winny The 4mm^2 wire was intended to minimize resistance problems that could arise since the wire is quite long. The question is mostly why it won't work with that long distance

Have you checked the voltage at your relay coil while it is operating?

@evildemonic I wish I could've checked but I'm not on site and I'm taking feedback from technicians who wired up the system. At this time I can only guess distance is the main problem here.

If the sensor relies on position to switch maybe the wires leading to the sensor have cycled enough times to become intermittent

@user30884 the sensor relies on water flowing onto it. It switches on when water covers its surface and switches off when there's no water.

The common solution for sensors on long wires are current loops. Voltage will drop over a long distance, but 100 mA is 100 mA. Of course, current sources will cap at a certain voltage when the switch is open and no current can run.

It's quite possible that length of wire pair could have enough mutual capacitance at 60Hz (maybe 50-100nF) to keep the relay from dropping out once it is pulled in. It would not prevent the relay from pulling in.
If this is the problem, a higher power relay coil or a resistor across the relay coil could make it go away.
Using DC is another possibility.
Consider this simulation. I've use a resistor for the relay coil which is not really accurate, but it should get the idea across. The boxes represent the cable. I've not tried to match the resistance of 1.6km of your wire, maybe it's close or not. The capacitance is based on ~75pF/m.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You can measure the voltage at the relay end and ensure that the parallel impedance reduces the voltage to safely below the voltage at which the relay is guaranteed to drop out. That should be in the relay datasheet, and can be as low as 10% of nominal voltage.
In practice the resistor wastes quite a bit of power if these seat-of-pants estimates are in the right ballpark so it might be better to use a resistor in series with a capacitor or something else like that. I would not, however, use a light bulb, as tempting as that might be, because it would cause intermittent problems when it burns out.
As you can see, with my guesstimate numbers, the relay sees more than 70VAC RMS with no resistor and with the particular resistor value I picked, less than 14VAC RMS.

Of course if you use DC then the capacitance will have little effect. 48VDC has long been a staple of telecom systems and you can investigate their findings on electrolytic action and such like, if applicable to your situation.
Since you have such hefty wires (equivalent to about AWG11) It might also be possible to use a lower voltage AC relay at similar coil power but you'd have to calculate the resistive losses. Using a lower voltage means there is proportionally less current through the capacitive reactance, and the relay will draw proportionally more current for the same coil power, so you get a \$\sigma^2\$ reduction in the unwanted effect. Going to a slightly more power-hungry relay in 120VAC might well be enough.

Thanks for your answer. What you described does happen, sometimes it latches but it won't pull out and I was experiencing water overflow of the tank (since the relay would not turn off). Also, would you mind showing in a circuit how the capacitance might be causing that problem and going further in detail on why adding a resistor across the coil would solve that issue?
